# Count Number of Saturdays in a date range - SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, count

I have a report which looks for orders during a given date range... It returns the DateName from the report to give me mondays, it then gives me times from the report, to give me 859 for 08:59 for example.. I then use a case on this report to do the following...

```
WHEN (DATENAME(DW,T1.DocDate)) = 'Monday' AND T1.DocTime >= '700' AND T1.DocTime <= '859' THEN '1 Monday 07:00-08:59'
```

What I want to achieve, is the count for "1 Monday 07:00-08:59" to be divided by 2 if there has been 2 mondays, divided by 3 if there has been 3 mondays etc... but I have to be able to have it divide by 3 mondays for example, but 2 wednesdays if the date is a tuesday...

The report currently gives a Total of all orders placed in a datetime grouped together but has no division to average for each day.

```
SELECT (DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate)) AS Weekday,
       T1.DocTime AS Time,
       SUM(T1.DocTotal) AS Value,
       CASE
            WHEN (DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate)) = 'Monday'
             AND T1.DocTime >= '700'
             AND T1.DocTime <= '859' THEN '1 Monday 07:00-08:59'
FROM ORDR T1
     INNER JOIN OCRD T0 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
WHERE (T1.DocDate >= @Start
   AND T1.DocDate <= @End)
  AND T0.QryGroup20 = 'Y'
  AND T1.Canceled = 'N'
GROUP BY T1.DocTime,
         T1.DocDate;
```

I expect the report to count the mondays / tuesdays etc that occur between @START and @END to give me an average sale per day and time.Then be able to then somehow divide by the count of the defined days in the case statement. (I'll hopefully be doing this part in Crystal Reports) but if i can get the first part, I'll work on the second half.

Comment: Use a calendar table. Will solve all your dates problems.

Comment: You should decide on an RDBMS too, SQL Server and MySQL are completely different ones. Also your `CASE` expression is missing an `END`, and this is worth while reading (as you're going to hate yourself if you keep aliasing things `T0`, `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, etc): [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic-

**For MSSQL**

```
DECLARE @DT1 DATE = '20190802'
DECLARE @DT2 DATE = '20190820'

DECLARE @SatCount INT = 0

WHILE @DT1<= @DT2
BEGIN

    SET @SatCount = @SatCount + CASE WHEN DATEPART(WeekDay,@DT1) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    SET @DT1 = DATEADD(DD,1,@DT1)
END


SELECT @SatCount
```

Just one more option-

```
DECLARE @DT1 DATE = '20190802',
        @DT2 DATE = '20190920';


SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WeekDay,Date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
(
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @DT1, @DT2) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @DT1)
    FROM    sys.all_objects a 
    -- A System table just used for creating multiple rows. 
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
    -- CROSS JOIN will create number of row = original number of row X original number of row. 
)A
```

Comment: There are better answers out there than using a `WHILE` loop. A `WHILE` is very likely the worst way due to it's RBAR nature, so it's going to be terribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Just cross join the DW_Count subquery, which returns the count of every weekday in your orders range. Then you can count your avg for each weekday

```
SELECT (DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate)) AS Weekday,
   T1.DocTime AS Time,
   SUM(T1.DocTotal) AS Value,
   SUM(T1.DocTotal)/(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Monday' then DW_Count.MonCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Tuesday' then DW_Count.TueCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Wednesday' then DW_Count.WedCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Thursday' then DW_Count.ThuCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Friday' then DW_Count.FriCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Saturday' then DW_Count.SatCount
                            WHEN DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate) = 'Sunday' then DW_Count.SunCount) AS AvgValue
   CASE
        WHEN (DATENAME(DW, T1.DocDate)) = 'Monday'
         AND T1.DocTime >= '700'
         AND T1.DocTime <= '859' THEN '1 Monday 07:00-08:59'    
FROM ORDR T1
 INNER JOIN OCRD T0 ON T0.CardCode = T1.CardCode
 CROSS JOIN (select sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Monday' then 1 else 0 end) as MonCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Tuesday' then 1 else 0 end) as TueCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Wednesday' then 1 else 0 end) as WedCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Thursday' then 1 else 0 end) as ThuCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Friday' then 1 else 0 end) as FriCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end) as SatCount,
    sum(case when DATENAME(DW, DW_Count.DateValue) = 'Sunday' then 1 else 0 end) as SunCount
        from (select distinct DocDate from ORDR where (T1.DocDate >= @Start AND T1.DocDate <= @End))) AS DW_Count
WHERE (T1.DocDate >= @Start
   AND T1.DocDate <= @End)
  AND T0.QryGroup20 = 'Y'
  AND T1.Canceled = 'N'
GROUP BY T1.DocTime,
         T1.DocDate;
```